# Multiple keys pressed in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple game and I need to check if multiple keys are pressed. A similar question received the following answer:

```
class MultiKeyPressListener implements KeyListener {

    // Set of currently pressed keys
    private final Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<Character>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());
        if (pressed.size() > 1) {
            // More than one key is currently pressed.
            // Iterate over pressed to get the keys.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        pressed.remove(e.getKeyChar());
    }

    @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {/* Not used */ }
    }
}
```

How do I "iterate over pressed to get the keys"? I came up with the following:

```
// declarations

private final Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<>();

// code

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {               
        pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());

        if(pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {  
            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: 
                starfighter.moveUpLeft();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                starfighter.moveUpRight();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

but this doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Thanks

Comment: What precisely you want to happen when both keys are pressed?

Comment: One of the methods;  moveUpLeft or moveUpRight needs to be executed, both of them work, I just don't know how to use keyevents in sets.

Comment: I think you'll have to preserve the keys pressed somehow outside the method and then check if all were pressed. Don't forget to clear the queue. Another solution is to remove break from case this way the checks will 'fall through'

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what's inside `pressed`?

Comment: Yes, but the set 'pressed' is not listed under variables

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the keyPressed method. There you will surely be able to inspect *pressed*.

Comment: it says: pressed = HashSet<E> id = (141) am I looking at the right info?

Comment: yes ... just open it and look what's inside ... what IDE do you use?

Comment: Eclipse, and when I select 'values' it says '0'

Comment: You need to inspect the set when you have the keys pressed.

Comment: I think I am doing that, as my input is recognized by the variable 'e'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
class MultiKeyPressListener implements KeyListener {

  // Set of currently pressed keys
  private final Set<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<Integer>();

  @Override
  public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    pressed.add(e.getKeyCode());

    if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
      if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
        starfighter.moveUpLeft();
      }
      if (pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
        starfighter.moveUpRight();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    pressed.remove(e.getKeyCode());
  }

  @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {/* Not used */ }
  }
}
```

Note how you have a set of Integers instead of Characters and store key codes instead of key characters.

Comment: Try this new version.

Comment: This answer could be improved by decoupling the `starfighter` from the keyboard logic. Instead, `MultiKeyPressListener ` should expose a snapshot (or a queue of snapshots) that the `starfighter` can read.